# Show form of other controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework-mvc

I'm new to Zend Framework 1 and I try to build a small blogsoftware (just to get into ZF1) and I've got following problem:

I want an user allow to comment an article of my site. Therefor I have two controller.
First one is the comment-controller with the action "create", the view "create" and the form "commentcreate".

The other controller is the article-controller with the action "showdetails" and the view "showdetails", where the user can see the whole article.

My question: Can I show the commentcreate-form on the showdetails-view? Or what is the right way to do something like that?

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with following flow:

Create `articleController`with `showdetailsAction` and instantiate your `commentcreate` form inside `showdetailsAction` itself. Create its view with details of your article along with comment form.

Create one more action inside `articleController` to add comment into the database which will be used when user will submit comment. For e.g. `createCommentAction`
When user will fill comment form and will submit that form at that time make an ajax request to server and call `createCommentAction` to store values in database.

Hope it is making sense.